# Swapped member values

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-optimization

I have something like this in my Visual C++ 2010 code:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo( int arg1, int arg2..)
  {
    var1=arg1;
    var2=arg2;
    ...
  };
  int var1;
  int var2;
  ...
};

struct Bar
{
  Bar(){};
  vector<Foo*> foos
}

vector<Bar> bars;
```

I am iterating through bars and then through bars[].foos, then doing something with Foo members. The problem is that sometimes I'm getting values of var1, var2... in wrong order.
This only happens in Release configuration; this also doesn't happen if Foo constructor looks like this:
    Foo ( arg1... ):var1(arg1)...
I'd like to understand what happened and why.

Comment: Are you saying that `var1` and `var2` get *incorrect* values, or that the values are correct but get set in an unexpected order?

Comment: Values are correct, they also appear to be in correct order if I query them directly. This only happens if I get those values through pointer.

Comment: It is most likely that you have made a mistake in some pointer arithmetic.  If you suspect a compiler bug, you'll need to come up with a short self-contained repro to demonstrate the problem.  It's impossible to diagnose this sort of issue with a few lines of pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was indeed my mistake, and stupid one.
Bar.foos were pointing to Foo objects in another vector which I forgot to reserve space for. So this vector was expanding from time to time, making my old pointers invalid. Naturally, Foo objects themselves were fine - they were just somewhere else.